# Почему не считываются новые значения intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast-receiver

У меня почему-то интент в ресивере сохраняет прошлые значения, а не новые которые я ему передаю.

`setOnetimeTimer` получает правильные новые значение, но в ресивере сохраняются прошлые. почему?

```
public void setOnetimeTimer(Context context, long when, Intent intentFromService) {

    id = intentFromService.getLongExtra("item_id", 0);
    dateto = intentFromService.getStringExtra("dateto");
    gender = intentFromService.getStringExtra("gender");
    event = intentFromService.getStringExtra("event");
    number = intentFromService.getStringExtra("phone");
    contact_name = intentFromService.getStringExtra("name");

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent2.putExtra("item_id", id);
    intent2.putExtra("dateto", dateto);
    intent2.putExtra("gender", gender);
    intent2.putExtra("event", event);
    intent2.putExtra("phone", number);
    intent2.putExtra("name", contact_name);
    intent2.putExtra("nowdate", date);


    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent2, 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, pi);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    id = intent.getLongExtra("item_id", 0);
    dateto = intent.getStringExtra("dateto");
    gender = intent.getStringExtra("gender");
    event = intent.getStringExtra("event");
    number = intent.getStringExtra("phone");
    contact_name = intent.getStringExtra("name");

    date = AddFunctionality.getCurrentData();

    try {
        DBHelper2 sqlHelper = new DBHelper2(context);
        sqlHelper.open();
        message = sqlHelper.getSmsText(gender, event);

        datasource = new DataSource(context);
        datasource.open();
        check = datasource.getAllTodayAlarm(date).get(0).getId();
        datasource.updateFlag(check);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SendSMS(context, number, message.get(0).getSms_text());
}
```

Comment: А где эти все переменные определены? Похоже, что их значения просто затираются. id = ... dateto = ... gender = ... event = ... number = ... contact_name = ...

Answer (score 1):

[Почитайте](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/204-urok-119-pendingintent-flagi-requestcode-alarmmanager.html) про PandingIntent, у вас сохраняются старые значения, потому что вы неправильный флаг кидаете и при одинаковых **PandingIntent**, а у вас они одинаковы по Aсtion приоритет уходит самому первому **PandingIntent**

Ошибка при создании **PendingIntent**

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent2, 0);
```

Вы налажали в конце, поставили 0.

вставьте вместо 0 вставьте **PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT** и будет вам счастье